# Phonegap - jQuery Mobile - Download/Save/Load File

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using Phonegap with jQuery Mobile and have the following use-case:

- I want to download a file from a remote server via JSON.
- Store the file on local filesystem of the mobile device (to work also offline).
- Target platforms: iOS, Android, maybe Windows Phone and BlackBerry.
- Load file from filesystem.

What's the recommended way to do that?

- Phonegap.FileWriter? Is there also a way to save it to "assets/www../"?
- Phonegap.Storage?

Or is there any better way?

Comment: Can you tell us what platforms you are targeting?

Comment: Android, ios and windowsphone

Comment: Hi user1165474, Have you solved this problem? Can you please post your answer, as I am having same kind of requirements.

Answer (score 1):

- Use XHR to download the JSON data.
- Use the FileWriter to save the file to the file system.
- Use the FileReader or XHR to read the JSON file from the file system.

No, you cannot save the file to assets/www as it is not writeable.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Do you have also experience with Storage? Whats the disadvantage of Storage? How long is the lifetime of Storage?

Comment: Storage is just a shim of window.openDatabase() for Android OS'es that don't support it or have a bug in their support. If you want to use a SQL database to store the data it is what you'd use.