# How to download and save a file locally, open it offline using Phonegap?

Tags: android, ios, filesystems, cordova, windows-phone

I am developing a cross-platform application. I came across Phonegap, which supports several mobile devices. But I am new in this field so I'm facing some issues.

I have a requirement, where the user downloads video files from a server and then opens those from local storage from mobile.

So how to achieve this using Phonegap, which should support iOS, Android and Windows.

I have already gone through:

- [Phonegap - jQuery Mobile - Download/Save/Load File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057129/phonegap-jquery-mobile-download-save-load-file)
- http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#LocalFileSystem

But I'm not getting proper documentation/tutorial. If there are any examples available then it would be helpful to check/debug.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'proper inputs'? Since you are using Phonegap, I assume you are trying to play HTML5 video in the web view container - correct?

Comment: Yes, But first user is downloading those videos to mobile local file storage. Then using local file url, opening that video file using video url in html. updated question - instead of inputs, used documentation

Answer (score 0):

A search on SO shows that on Android there are some issues with HTML5 video and Phonegap:

[Phonegap 2.3 and Android with HTML5 video tag in 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810170/phonegap-2-3-and-android-with-html5-video-tag-in-2013)

At least in Window Phone 7 there are some tricks as well (storage path related).

[How to play embedded video in WP7 - Phonegap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326008/how-to-play-embedded-video-in-wp7-phonegap)

Which may explain why there isn't a single multi-platform example which is what I think you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What!, there is no single solution :( and yeah I am looking for general solution that's why I have chosen HTML+Phonegap as a platform.